# Use backgroundColor in DT package to change a complete row instead of a single value

Tags: r, colors, shiny, dt

The answer is probably obvious but i've been looking into using the  backgroundColor attribute in the DT package to change the color of the full row instead of only the value that i use to select the row and I didn't manage to do it.

So basically in my Shiny app, I have a DataTable output in my server file  where i wrote this :

```
output$tableMO <- DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(DFSurvieMO,
              options = 
                list( displayStart= numerMO()-2,
                      pageLength = 15,
                      lengthChange = FALSE, searching =FALSE),rownames= FALSE) %>% formatStyle(
      c(1:2),
      backgroundColor = 
        if(numerMO()>1) {
          styleInterval(c(DFSurvieMO[,1][numerMO()-1],DFSurvieMO[,1][numerMO()]), c('blank','lightblue', 'blank'))
        }
        else {
          styleInterval(DFSurvieMO[,1][numerMO()], c('lightblue', 'blank'))}

      )
    })
```

And what i get in my app is a DataTable with only a single cell colored. I tried using `target = 'row'` but either I didn't put it in the right place or it does not work. So how can i get it to color the whole row ?
Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write some custom `JS` function using `rowCallback`. Below I have written a reactive which will listen to the `slider` and if the `slider` values in the `mtcars` dataset are bigger than your value it will repaint the row. Note that the `aData[1]` is the column called `cyl` within the `mtcars` dataset.

Apologies for not using your code as I wanted to make a more generic example

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- basicPage(
  sliderInput("trigger", "Trigger",min = 0, max = 10, value = 6, step= 1),
  mainPanel(DT::dataTableOutput('my_table'))
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {

  my_callback <- reactive({
    my_callback <- 'function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {if (parseFloat(aData[1]) >= TRIGGER)$("td", nRow).css("background-color", "#9BF59B");}'
    my_callback <- sub("TRIGGER",input$trigger,my_callback)
    my_callback
  })

  output$my_table = DT::renderDataTable(    
    datatable(mtcars,options = list(
      rowCallback = JS(my_callback()),searching = FALSE,paging = FALSE),rownames = FALSE)
  ) 
}
runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

[image]

Comment: Ok so I guess this is what I was looking for, I don't know JS though so I may have a hard time applying this to my code, but unless there is an option in R to do the same thing, I'll give this method a try. Thank You

Comment: The more you use it the better. Don't get discouraged if you don't know it. It is not as bad as you think. I didn't write this by the way I found an example on GitHub a long time ago