# renderDataTable color pre selected rows

Tags: r, datatable, shiny, shinydashboard

This is an example that shows how to select a column (Column 3), highlight the values that are greater than 100 certain way and highlight values that are greater than 200 certain way.

```
library("shiny")
library("shinydashboard")
library("datasets")
library("DT")

header <- dashboardHeader()

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar()

body <- dashboardBody(
  DT::dataTableOutput("mtcarsTable")
)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body),
  server = function(input, output) {

    output$mtcarsTable <- renderDataTable({
      DT::datatable(datasets::mtcars, 
                    options = list(rowCallback = JS('
                                                    function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
                                                    // Bold and green cells for conditions
                                                    if (parseFloat(aData[3]) >= 200)
                                                    $("td:eq(3)", nRow).css("font-weight", "bold");
                                                    if (parseFloat(aData[3]) >= 100)
                                                    $("td:eq(3)", nRow).css("background-color", "#9BF59B");
                                                    }')
                      )
                    )
  })
  }
                    )
```

I am just looking for a way to select just the rows and not columns. For example , select row 3, 9, 11 and 13 and color these rows yellow. Any help on how to modify the code above inorder to accomplish this is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like `aData` is a dataframe.

Is there any reason why you can't refer to `aData[c(3,9,11,13),]` ?

Comment: @Warner,  you are right `aData` is a dataframe, I did what you suggested, I did not see any output , nor did i see any error, i suspect i would have to change the next line as well, `$("td:eq(3)", nRow).....` but not sure how ?

Comment: @Science11, have a look at my example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38565033/use-backgroundcolor-in-dt-package-to-change-a-complete-row-instead-of-a-single-v/38565223#38565223

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for but the code below will highlight in yellow all the rows where the value of the "disp" (aData[3]) column is greater than 200.

```
'function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
 if (parseFloat(aData[3]) >= 200)
 $(nRow).css("background-color", "#ffff00");
 }'
```

Just insert it in the rowCallback part.

Alternatively,

edit your code to remove the column number:

```
$("td", nRow).css("background-color", "#9BF59B");
```